# Cannot copy and paste text from local system to remote system while using Teamviewer 12

Tags: linux, windows, copy-paste, teamviewer

I cannot copy and paste text from my local system (Windows 10) to remote system (RHEL 6.6) and vice-versa while using Teamviewer 12. I can type things normally on my remote system and the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) work ONLY for the remote system (I can only copy and paste text within the facilities of the remote system. For instance, I cannot copy text from the local system and paste it on my remote system).

I followed the suggestions in this [forum post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27688278/How-to-enable-Clipboard-access-in-TeamViewer.html) but most of them did not work for me. I don't understand what "Edit>Paste function in a remote application" means.

Apart from this discrepancy, all the Teamviewer facilities that I need are working perfectly.

Comment: Have you looked in the TeamViewer options?

Comment: I have. `Easy Access` and `Send key combinations` are enabled on my local system.

Comment: *I don't understand what "Edit>Paste function in a remote application" means.* - It means in the application running on the remote system, use the copy and paste functionality of said application, to copy and paste the content.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried that for the text editor on my remote system (RHEL 6.6). I can paste on the text editor ONLY what I had copied or cut on the remote system. I cannot copy text from my local system (Windows 10) and paste THAT text anywhere on my remote system.

Comment: @a_sid Looks like you needed to restart TeamViewer but my explanation of the statement was still correct

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer got closed on my remote system once and after reopening it, the "Copy and Paste" feature began working properly. I can now copy and paste text from my local to remote systems and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was offered in the post you linked but it seems you're after making the clipboard shared between the two systems.
TeamViewer has an option for this,
Extras > Options > Advanced > Sync Clipboard

This should be checked on your local machine's TeamViewer, the one launching the session. I'm not 100% sure if it needs to be checked on the other end too, but it can't hurt.

"Edit>Paste function in a remote application" is just saying manually go to the menu and paste, instead of using "ctrl+v" to see if it is the shortcut key that is not working, or the clipboard that is not working.
Since you've said that you can copy and paste within the remote session, it is not the shortcut keys, but the clipboards not being shared.

If you're still having trouble, try googling specifically for clipboard share teamviewer.

Comment: Clipboard synchronization is enabled on both the remote and local systems for me.